# Xamarin How to store a date from a Date Picker

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a DatePicker in Xamarin, but am confused how to store the selected date to a variable whenever a new date is selected in the DatePicker.

This is my current code:

```
private void DateSelected(object sender, DateTime e)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)e;
            Debug.WriteLine(date);
        }
```

But the date keeps defaulting to 1/1/0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler isn't quite right. *e* is not a DateTime but a *DateChangedEventArgs*, which *contains* the DateTime selected. Your code should be:

```
private void DatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime newDate = e.NewDate;
}
```